# Was Rukmini at Vrindavan when she was young?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, radha, vrindavana

What is the birth star of Goddess Radharani? There seems to be very few references of young Rukmini Devi. Was she at Vrindavan as Radharani during that time?

Comment: No, they are not the same. Rukmini is sister of Rukmi. Radha is adopted daughter of Vrishabhanu.

Comment: Radha is the 'adopted' daughter of Vrishabanu. This is exactly where my doubt comes. I couldn't find any references to Rukmini's childhood. Could she have been kidnapped by any asura and left near Vrishabanu? And then there is the case of Radha. After Krishna leaves for Mathura, there is no mention of Radha so he might have instructed her to return to Vidarbha, her original kingdom and wait for him.

Comment: Sri Krishna had met his parents Yashoda and Nandagopa and other gopis after the war. There also it is not specifically mentioned that he met Radha.

Comment: Partial duplicate of [Were Radha and Rukmini the same person?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16303/5212). The question whether Radha and Rukmini are same is already asked. [edit] out that question to avoid duplicate closure. Please take a [tour]. You can a look at questions tagged [tag:radha] for more questions which were frequently asked.

Comment: Radha was married to someone else and later after her husbands dead she met krishna and realised that love for krishna was more mentally than physical attracted.It is mentioned in one old book.After dead she was united with krishna

Answer (score 3):

There is no basis for Rukmini and Radha being one.

Rukmini is daughter of Bhismaka, a king of Vidarbha.

Radha is daughter of Vrishabanu in Vrindavan.

Rukmini didn't see Krishna before Krishna kidnapped her to marry. It appears that she developed desire to have Krishna as husband only by hearing about him. Hence, she can't be Radha who saw Krishna in Vrindavan.

> SB 10.52.23: Hearing of the beauty, prowess, transcendental character
>   and opulence of Mukunda from visitors to the palace who sang His
>   praises, Rukmiṇī decided that He would be the perfect husband for her.
>
> SB 10.52.37: Śrī Rukmiṇī said [in her letter, as read by the
>   brāhmaṇa]: O beauty of the worlds, having heard of Your qualities,
>   which enter the ears of those who hear and remove their bodily
>   distress, and having also heard of Your beauty, which fulfills all the
>   visual desires of those who see, I have fixed my shameless mind upon
>   You, O Kṛṣṇa.