# Who was incarnation of Laxmi: Radha Rani or Rukmini Devi?

Tags: krishna, avatars

Who was the incarnation of Laxmi - **RadhaRani** or **Rukmani Devi** ?

I have tried to find this on internet but I did not find an answer yet .

Comment: Related or possibly Duplicate - [Were Radha and Rukmini the same person?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16303/were-radha-and-rukmini-the-same-person)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting texts from the [Bhagavata Purana](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/52/16-17/):

> "O hero among the Kurus, the Supreme Lord Himself, Govinda, married
> Bhīṣmaka’s daughter, **Vaidarbhī, who was a direct expansion of the
> goddess of fortune**. The Lord did this by her desire, and in the
> process He beat down Śālva and other kings who took Śiśupāla’s side.
> Indeed, as everyone watched, Śrī Kṛṣṇa took Rukmiṇī just as Garuḍa
> boldly stole nectar from the demigods."

Next quoting from the [Vishnu Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vishnu-purana-wilson/d/doc115945.html):

From both verses it is clear that rukmini is incarnation of goddess lakshmi.

> "Parāśara proceeded:— Thus, Maitreya, in former times the goddess Śrī
> conferred these boons upon the king of the gods, being pleased by his
> adorations; but her first birth was as the daughter of Bhrigu by
> Khyāti: it was at a subsequent period that she was produced from the
> sea, at the churning of the ocean by the demons and the gods, to
> obtain ambrosia[11]. For in like manner as the lord of the world, the
> god of gods, Janārddana, descends amongst mankind (in various shapes),
> so does his coadjutrix Śrī. Thus when Hari was born as a dwarf, the
> son of Aditī, Lakṣmī appeared from a lotus (as Padmā, or Kamalā); when
> he was born as Rāma, of the race of Bhrigu (or Paraśurāma), she was
> Dharaṇī; when he was Rāghava (Rāmacandra), she was Sītā; and **when he
> was Kṛṣṇa, she became Rukminī**. In the other descents of Viṣṇu, she
> is his associate. If he takes a celestial form, she appears as divine;
> if a mortal, she becomes a mortal too, transforming her own person
> agreeably to whatever character it pleases Viṣṇu to put on. Whosoever
> hears this account of the birth of Lakṣmī, whosoever reads it, shall
> never lose the goddess Fortune from his dwelling for three
> generations; and misfortune, the fountain of strife, shall never enter
> into those houses in which the hymns to Śrī are repeated."

And, lastly quoting from the [Devi Bhagavata Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57314.html):

> 1. Śri Nārāyaṇa said :-- This (Highest) Prakṛti is recognised as five-fold.
>
> When She is engaged in the work of Creation, She appears as :-- (1)
> Durgā, the Mother of Gaṇeśa,  (**2) Rādhā, (3) Laksm**ī, (4) Sarasvatī
> and (5) Sāvitrī.

So From here it is clear that radha devi is different from goddess lakshmi and both radha and lakshmi are among 5 forms of highest prakriti.

Comment: Images are not required if you can copy and paste from the site directly. Also one needs to add the quoted texts in the blockquote. Our own words should not be in blockquotes though. @RaghavGoyal

Comment: @Rickross i don't know how to convert links ,and how to type in different font , so I used the same font.Thanks for editing.

Comment: That's ok. We have also learned in this manner. If you follow how I did it it won't be a problem for you the next time @RaghavGoyal

Answer (score 5):

The incarnation of Sri (Laxmi) was Rukmini as mentioned in [Mahabharata: Adi Parva: Sambhava Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01068.htm):

> And, O king, the portions of the tribe of Apsaras which I have mentioned already, also became incarnate on earth according to Indra's commands--And sixteen thousand portions of those goddesses became, O king, in this world of men, the wives of Vasudeva. **And a portion of Sri herself** became incarnate on earth, for the gratification of Narayana, in the line of Bhishmaka. And she was by name the chaste **Rukmini**. And the faultless Draupadi, slender-waisted like the wasp, was born of a portion of Sachi (the queen of the celestials), in the line of Drupada.

Goddess Radha's details are not found in Mahabharata, Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa) and Vishnu Purana etc. As per Brahmavaivarta Purana, Radha was incarnation of Goddess Radha of Goloka (more details are in [Was Radha aunt of Krishna?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31795/was-radha-aunt-of-krishna/31808#31808) post).

Comment: Pls.see my comment above and pls. do check  whether it's a  duplicate post.

Comment: looks like not a dupe of that..may be a dupe of this umbrella Q https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/28269/12304 (for incarnations of all MBH characters)

Answer (score 4):

One more reference from the **Lakshmi Tantra, Chapter 8**

> अवतारो हि यो विष्णोश्चतुर्धा संभविष्यति ।
> मधुरायामहं व्यक्तिं चतुर्धैष्यामि वै तथा ॥ ४५॥
> रेवती रुक्मिणी चैव रतिर्नाम्ना तथा ह्युषा।

> When Vishnu will incarnate in four forms (Balarama, Krishna,  pradyumana and Aniruddha), at Madhura, I too will take four forms. (They are) Revati, Rukmini, Rati and Usha.